# Adding an Action listener to a JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, awt, jcombobox

I'd like to know how can I add a ActionListener to JComboBox. I'm using AWT. Can you explain it to me? Thanks.

Comment: you should also learn how to use the Java API http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/  because some questions like these should be answered easily with small amount of search.

Answer (score 6):

Note First : there is no comboBox item in awt, there is JComboBox in Swing which is better to use than Choice of awt.

```
JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();

comboBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                //Execute when a selection has been made

            }
        });
```

Or you can define a class that implements ActionListener and define the `actionPerformed` method there, and once you do that, you can just add a new instance of that class to your JComboBox addActionListener method.

If any of that didn't make sense to you, you can check the follwing website: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html

Answer (score 2):

You should not use awt except you are confined to (i.e. an applet), otherwise prefer swing or swt.

If you use `Choice` from `java.awt`, it has a `addItemListener(ItemListener l)` method.

If you used swing, `JComboBox` has a `addActionListener` method.

Comment: There is no reason to use AWT in applets.  (Unless you consider providing support for MS' obsolete, insecure VM to be a 'reason' - I don't).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know somethig about `AWT ComboBox` there is only [Choice](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Choice.html), and AWT Componets silently d*i*e*d sometime in last milenium, for todays GUI is required [Swing JComponents](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html)

for [JComboBox](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) you can implements [ActionListener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html), but I think that you have to use this `Listener`if you want/needed to change `JComboBox` itself,

for `JComboBox` I suggest that better `Listener` for `JComboBox` is [ItemListener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/itemlistener.html), because there are three important states `ItemEvent.SELECTED, DESELECTED and ITEM_STATE_CHANGED`

notice `JComboBox` has two states Editable and non-Editable

EDIT: for clear mind and enjoy from programing don't mixing `AWT Components` and with `Swing JComponents`, in other hands, sure that possible from JDK1.6_012 more [here](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/mixing/) and [here](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/GUI/mixing_components/), but for nice and correct output to the GUI you have to needed lots of skills about Java GUI